# Making a *nicely* formatted list of number of files in directories - awk & sed probably

Tags: text-processing, ls, filenames, text-formatting

I have lots and lots of files in a series of directories, and would like a *nicely formatted* list of how many files are in each directory.

The directories are ordered thus:  Parent directories named A, B, ... H, I.  Under each of these, there are from 1 to 7 directories named 001, 002, ... 007.  In these directories, the files I'd like a count of files.

What I'm hoping for, is something like this:

```
...
C/003    122
C/004     45
C/005    462
D/001    215
E/001     98
E/002    323
...
```

I'm thinking a tab between directory-name and count.  It doesn't matter if the count is left or right justified.

What I've done myself is basically this:

```
( for i in */*
do
  echo ">>> $i"
  ls "$i" | wc
done ) > file_count
```

The result is something like this:

```
...
>>> F/002
  30   30   234
>>> F/003
  120  120  1322
>>> G/001
  78   78   620
...
```

Obviously, not bad... and if I replaced `wc` with `wc -l` and removed the ">>>" it would be even better - *except* that each "record" would be over two lines rather than one.

So what I need, is some `awk` or `sed` (or *whatever* - is there a simpler tool for joining two lines than those two?) magic to join the two-and-two lines into one.

However, if there is a more direct approach (shell-script, perl, python, some *really dark* sed & awk magic) that could make a list in "one go", that would be even better...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file names don't contain newline characters and your `grep` supports the -o option:

```
find [[:upper:]] -type f | grep -Eo '^./[0-9]{3}' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: FYI this guy discovered the shellshock bug in bash

Answer (score 0):

You can built an array of files for each directory separately, and then just count the number of elements. In `bash` that would be something like

```
for dir in */*/; do a=( "$dir"/* ); printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#a[@]}"; done
```

If `A/001` etc. contains directories too which content you would like to include, then add `**` glob:

```
shopt -s globstar
for dir in */*/; do a=( "$dir"/**/* ); printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#a[@]}"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get what you want is to use the `-n` option to `echo` when you print the directory name. That avoids printing a newline at the end of whatever you're echoing, so the next output stays on the same line. Other languages may be a better option if you want to collect the information you're looking for and then run multiple transformations on it before giving output.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```
find $PWD/ -type f -printf "%h\n\0" | uniq -zc
```

Yield something like:

```
  7 /foo
 17 /foo/bar
  9 /foo/baz
```

Add a `| sort -z` before `| uniq` to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you've asked:

```
for d in */*
do
    n=$(find "$d" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "ok\n" | wc -l)
    printf "%s\t%d\n" "$d" $n
done
```

The primary differences to your code are that I've used `find` instead of `ls` so that weirdly named files won't break the count (think of `\n` in a filename), and that I've used `printf` to format the output.